# Viz LDA model with Bokeh and T-sne

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, lda

I have tried to follow this tutorial (https://shuaiw.github.io/2016/12/22/topic-modeling-and-tsne-visualzation.html) of visualizing LDA with t-sne and bokeh.
But i run into a bit of problem. 
When i tried to run the following code:

```
    plot_lda.scatter(x=tsne_lda[:, 0], y=tsne_lda[:, 1],
             color=colormap[_lda_keys][:num_example],
             source=bp.ColumnDataSource({
               "content": text[:num_example],
               "topic_key": _lda_keys[:num_example]
               }))
```

NB: In the tutorial the content is called news, in mine it is called text

i get this error:

Supplying a user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods is
not possibe. Either:

Pass all data directly as literals:

```
p.circe(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)
```

Or, put all data in a ColumnDataSource and pass column names:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))
p.circe(x='x', y='x', source=source, ...)
```

To me this do not make so much sense and  i have not succeded in finding any annswer to it ethier here, github or else where. Hope that some on can help. best Niels

Answer (score 2):

I've been also battling with that piece of code and I've found two problems with it.

First, when you pass a source to the scatter function, like the error states, you must include all data in the dictionary, i.e., x and y axes, colors, labels, and any other information that you want to include in the tooltip.

Second, the x and y axes have a different shape than the information passed to the tooltip, so you also have to slice both arrays in the axes with the `num_example` variable.

The following code got me running:

```
# create the dictionary with all the information    
plot_dict = {
        'x': tsne_lda[:num_example, 0],
        'y': tsne_lda[:num_example, 1],
        'colors': colormap[_lda_keys][:num_example],
        'content': text[:num_example],
        'topic_key': _lda_keys[:num_example]
        }

# create the dataframe from the dictionary
plot_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(plot_dict)

# declare the source    
source = bp.ColumnDataSource(data=plot_df)
title = 'LDA viz'

# initialize bokeh plot
plot_lda = bp.figure(plot_width=1400, plot_height=1100,
                     title=title,
                     tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,hover,previewsave",
                     x_axis_type=None, y_axis_type=None, min_border=1)

# build scatter function from the columns of the dataframe
plot_lda.scatter('x', 'y', color='colors', source=source)
```